# Wonder Woman and world history in the DCEU

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, history, wonder-woman-2017

In the Wonder Woman movie, she

> kills General Ludendorff,

who is a very important historical person. If you consider Hitler's rise for power, the Beer Hall Putsch from November 1933 would not have had this impact on Hitler's carreer, if he had not been allied with Hitler.

If it weren't for

> Ludendorff

Hitler would have been one of many right-wingers, trying to overthrow the Weimar Government. A sidenote of history.

Which brings me to my question. What do we know about World War II and Hitler in the DCEU? I am not going to sit through any of these movies anytime soon, but is there information about anything concerning World War II? Maybe even figures of speech? Because,

> killing not just a fictional Person but the actual Ludendorff off

has heavy consequences, IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

We know very little specifically about World War II, and Hitler, in the DCEU, for the simple reason that no events have taken place in that time period during the films.

With no evidence that there is any difference in the events of WWII, it is reasonable to assume that there are no substantive differences.  Hitler rose to power with the assistance of other generals and supporters, and without Ludendorff's help.

One could make the  argument that the rise of Hitler is one of those "fixed points in time" that so many sci-fi series like to discuss, where it's very VERY hard to prevent their happening, and actually succeeding would make such a radical change in history as to fire off paradoxes aplenty.

We have a LOT more information about World War II in the comics, because there were stories being written during that period.  The main thing we know is that as powerful as Earth's heroes were at the time, they were largely unable to interact in the war in any major way due to Hitler's use of the Spear of Destiny.

I believe it was Roy Thomas in All Star Squadron who concocted the idea that Hitler used the Spear to create a barrier across most of Europe that prevented "super-heroes" from entering, effectively leaving them out of the battle. A similar artifact (the name of which I'm too lazy to look up) blocked access to the Asian battlefront as well.

This was a contrivance created to answer the eternal question "Why didn't Superman just fly into Berlin, grab Hitler and his cronies, and deliver them to the world court or whatever?" The real-world answer is of course it would result in a wildly different world in the comics, one that might cause people to lose interest in the stories, and possibly even cause a change in military morale. Remember, at the time, many soldiers read comics, and stories were frequently written to prop up morale.  There were plenty of tales that centered around "we heroes can't do it all - the brave men of the military are the REAL heroes"

Comment: "Where it's very VERY to prevent their happening" Can you edit this please?

Comment: That does not answer my question. Is am well aware, that no films have taken place in the WWII era, but events that shaped our contemporary world happened in that era. For example, we would not have a United Nations Organisation, but still the League of Nations (if anything). What I am looking for are bits and pieces like this. Maybe, I need to elaborate on my question to make that clear.

Comment: @BaronFurzgesicht: Our world does not have Metropolis, Gotham City, Central City or Midway City. So DC takes liberty from our history and geography when it sees fit. In addition, though it is not mentioned in the DCEU so far, DC is known to have many parallel universes (and they are not shy of using parallel universes in non-comics works, see the TV shows). So it is safe to assume that this answer is the best answer to the question we can get so far.